# akka HttpResponse read body as String scala

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

So I have a function with this signature (akka.http.model.HttpResponse):

```
def apply(query: Seq[(String, String)], accept: String): HttpResponse
```

I simply get a value in a test like:

```
val resp = TagAPI(Seq.empty[(String, String)], api.acceptHeader)
```

I want to check its body in a test something like:

```
resp.entity.asString == "tags"
```

My question is how I can get the response body as string?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31532838/390708

Comment: Are you using `akka-http-testkit`? If yes, you can use `entityAs[String]` in the test to get the body as a String value.

Comment: I need to use PlaySpec so I cant use akka-http-testkit :(

Comment: I noticed that `entityAs[String]` does not work if akka-http-circe's `FailFastCirceSupport` (1.22.0) was brought into context. Work-around was to move the import.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal

implicit val system = ActorSystem("System")  
implicit val materializer = ActorFlowMaterializer() 

val responseAsString: Future[String] = Unmarshal(entity).to[String]
```

Comment: Which akka-http-core version are you using for that? With 2.4.6, I don't find the `akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling`, anywhere.

Comment: @akauppi this is `akka-http-experimental` not `akka-http-core`

Comment: Unfortunately `Unmarshal` lives in `akka-http` artifact (not `akka-http-core` or `akka-http-client`).

Comment: Think it should be ActorMaterializer() rather than ActorFlowMaterializer()?

Answer (score 30):

Since Akka Http is streams based, the entity is streaming as well. If you really need the entire string at once, you can convert the incoming request into a `Strict` one:

This is done by using the `toStrict(timeout: FiniteDuration)(mat: Materializer)` API to collect the request into a strict entity within a given time limit (this is important since you don't want to "try to collect the entity forever" in case the incoming request does actually never end):

```
import akka.stream.ActorFlowMaterializer
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys") // your actor system, only 1 per app
implicit val materializer = ActorFlowMaterializer() // you must provide a materializer

import system.dispatcher
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val timeout = 300.millis

val bs: Future[ByteString] = entity.toStrict(timeout).map { _.data }
val s: Future[String] = bs.map(_.utf8String) // if you indeed need a `String`
```

Comment: Its seems to be a good way, but what kind of implicit FlowMaterializer are you using? (You get it from import or use some default implementation?)

Comment: You can just create one ad hoc or re-use an existing instance, I amended my response.

Comment: I think the unmarshaller is the most current way to do this so I reassigned the answer tick.

Comment: Either's fine I suppose. Cheers

Comment: Wow, why is timeout and a required argument? Way to make it more complicated and cumbersome to use.. sensible default would be much better.

Answer (score 12):

You can also try this one also.

```
responseObject.entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).map(_.utf8String) map println
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Unmarshaller.stringUnmarshaller(someHttpEntity)
```

works like a charm, implicit materializer needed as well

Answer (score 5):

Here is simple directive that extracts `string` from request's body

```
def withString(): Directive1[String] = {
  extractStrictEntity(3.seconds).flatMap { entity =>
    provide(entity.data.utf8String)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately in my case, `Unmarshal` to String didn't work properly complaining on: `Unsupported Content-Type, supported: application/json`. That would be more elegant solution, but I had to use another way. In my test I used Future extracted from entity of the response and Await (from scala.concurrent) to get the result from the Future:

```
Put("/post/item", requestEntity) ~> route ~> check {
  val responseContent: Future[Option[String]] =
  response.entity.dataBytes.map(_.utf8String).runWith(Sink.lastOption)

  val content: Option[String] = Await.result(responseContent, 10.seconds)
  content.get should be(errorMessage)
  response.status should be(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
}
```

If you need to go through all lines in a response, you can use `runForeach` of Source:

```
 response.entity.dataBytes.map(_.utf8String).runForeach(data => println(data))
```

Comment: This solution works for me even though I'm extending `FailFastCirceSupport`. Some of the other answers that rely on `Unmarshal(…).to[String]` didn't work, probably because I'm extending that trait.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working example,

```
  import akka.actor.ActorSystem
  import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
  import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
  import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
  import akka.util.ByteString

  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }

  def getDataAkkaHTTP:Unit = {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    // needed for the future flatMap/onComplete in the end
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val url = "http://localhost:8080/"
    val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = url))

    responseFuture.onComplete {
      case Success(res) => {
        val HttpResponse(statusCodes, headers, entity, _) = res
        println(entity)
        entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).foreach (body => println(body.utf8String))
        system.terminate()
      }
      case Failure(_) => sys.error("something wrong")
    }


  }
```

Comment: Ref: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html#example