# Get the JSON from HttpEntity

Tags: json, scala, akka, httpresponse, httpentity

I am using akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse, HttpEntity.

After getting the response , it is of type responseEntity of the format (Content-type: 'application/json', {MyJSONHERE}). Is there a way I can extract my json from the entity.

I tried entity.getDataBytes which gives the content of the entity in ByteString format. I want to properly read the JSON and parse it. Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/32315789/864369

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code below works for me

```
entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.fold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _)).map(_.utf8String) map { result =>
  JsonMethods.parse(result)
}
```

`dataBytes` returns `Source[ByteString, Any]`, `Sink.fold` combines all parts of the stream into one `ByteString` and `utf8String` converts `ByteString` into usual `String`.

Here is some useful docs about [HttpEntity](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.7/scala/http/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code?

```
entity.getDataBytes.utf8String
```

That would return String representation of JSON.

Comment: utfString is not getting recognized as a valid function

Comment: for an accessing `utf8String`,  `entity.getDataBytes` must return ByteString and ByteString class has utf8String function.

Comment: you are using `utfString` not `utf8String`